# Connection does not close like it should

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlconnection

I am encountering the following error in my ASP project:

```
The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open
```

While calling the .open() function on a SqlConnection Object.

I have tried this :

```
    if (Conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        Log.Message(xxx);
        try
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(xxxx);
        }
    }
    Conn.Open();
```

But this still raises the error. The Conn object is declared as:

```
private static readonly SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(xxxx);
```

Any idea where I should look for a solution

Comment: Ideally, `SqlConnection` objects should be created in `using` statements where they're created, opened, used, and then (by reaching the end of the `using` statement) `Dispose`d. Having a `static` one in your program suggests that you're trying to keep one around for a long time and reuse it - which isn't generally a good idea.

Comment: There are other states besides `Closed` and `Open`.  Perhaps the connection is in some other state, so the `try` block doesn't get executed?

Comment: Is the same connection accessed via different threads at the same time?

Comment: What's is the `Conn.State` just before `Conn.Open()`?

Comment: Do you have any SqlDataReaders that are still in use at the point you try to close the connection?

Comment: It is used on multiple places in the project and via different threads the connection is always closed in the finally block

Comment: @PatrickNijhuis: SqlConnection objects are not thread safe.  That's your issue.

Comment: If you're declaring the connection as `static`, that sets off all kinds of alarm bells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the pattern.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(someSql, conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQueryOrWhatevs();
}
```

1. Create your connection
2. Open your connection
3. Dispose of your connection

Don't try to reuse it.  Just get it, use it, and dispose of it as fast as possible.

Also, none of this is thread safe, so don't be touching any of the above instances from different threads.  One thread to use the connection only, please.  Feel free to use multiple threads to process the results.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to close the connection and disposed object is 'Finally' you should go for it.
OR better to use Using to dispose all objects and close connections see below snippet

```
public void run_runcommand(string query)   
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            // ...
        }
   }       // close not needed since dispose also closes the connection
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and grab a copy of the Framework Design Guidelines.